# Jekyll + Github Pages with .md return 404s

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

While I'm trying to figure out how to get this working on my local so I can test more effectively, I'm running into a 404 error when deploying via Github Pages.

I have a folder structure to help me keep everything clean. The readme.md files in every folder are all rendering with the expected layout in the current theme (Dinky). By default, every other markdown file is rendering as raw.

If I add any front matter whatsoever, that page turns into a 404.

Have tried blank front matter:

```
---
---
```

title:

```
---
title: My page
---
```

layout:

```
---
layout: default
---
```

permalink

```
---
permalink: /Ar-sho/Stories/Lynunan/1_A_Fire_Too_Bright.md
---
```

And many combinations of the above.

Example with front matter:

https://freer4.github.io/Ar-sho/Stories/Lynunan/1_A_Fire_Too_Bright.md

Example without front matter:

https://freer4.github.io/Ar-sho/Stories/Lynunan/2_Kashatu_Stand.md

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL once front matter is added should end in .html

https://freer4.github.io/Ar-sho/Stories/Lynunan/1_A_Fire_Too_Bright.html